# Plot multiple irregular timeseries on same line chart dojo

Tags: javascript, charts, dojo, dojox.charting

I am looking to create a line chart which will plot an array of data which has a corresponding x value (date/time) and y value associated with it. The chart can have any number of series (different lines on the same graph). You can think of this as like how yahoo/google graph a particular stock and if you want to compare different companies stock prices on the same chart.

The problem I am facing is that the data I am given might not be given in regular intervals (e.g. series 1 might give an array of plots that occur every 15 mins, series2 might be 10 mins, etc). Also the data might not have the same start / end time (e.g. series 1 starts at 8:40 am, series 2 starts at 8:42 am). There can also be holes in the data where no data was gathered (want to display this as nothing in the chart)

I have thought about some potential ways to solve this problem

1. Put everything on a 1 minute interval (the smallest possible interval) and place null values for everything we do not have data for. I need to have null values because there are datatips on the graph when you hover over a point to tell you what the value is at that point. The problem with this is that this will cause the graph to become a point graph rather than a line graph and will look ugly. I can tell dojo to interpret the data between null values but I also want to have explicit null values (e.g. when the market is not open leave the space as nothing rather than connecting the lines)
2. Round the data to the closest interval. The problem with this is the data is no longer accurate for that particular moment which is a problem.
3. Don't allow them to be plotted together (not an option).
4. Use a different charting library (last resort)

I am using the dojox charting library and I cannot change the back end code that gives me the data.

What are my options?